# How to use Colorbox with external link?

Tags: 8, javascript

I have a site built with Drupal 8.3.7.
Modules 'Colorbox', 'Colorbox Load', 'Colorbox Inline' and 'NG Lightbox' are activated.
I can't make this kind of thing work:

```
<a class="colorbox-load" href="http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?msa=0&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=p&amp;vpsrc=6&amp;msid=216664623938073990188.0004abcd95a296bf10c39&amp;ll=48.552978,-0.736084&amp;spn=3.636247,8.778076&amp;z=7&amp;output=embed&amp;width=800&amp;height=400&amp;iframe=true"><img alt="" src="/falzon/sites/default/files/201107/J1.png" style="height:400px; max-width:none; width:800px" title="Cliquer pour ouvrir dans Google Maps" /></a></p>
```

giving that:
[image]
while it works perfectly in Drupal 7.
Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could load external content replacing your href by

```
javascript:void jQuery.colorbox({html:'<iframe width=854 height=480 src=http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?parameters=example frameborder=0 allowfullscreen></iframe>'})
```

It will be something like:

```
<a href="javascript:void jQuery.colorbox({html:'<iframe width=854 height=480 src=http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?parameters=example frameborder=0 allowfullscreen></iframe>'})">colorbox-load external link</a>
```